# Recibir pk de un objeto en una CreateView Django

Tags: django, django-urls

Como puedo obtener  en una CreateView el pk de un objeto para asignarlo a otro que tiene un ForeignKey field.

**Model.py**

```
class Manga(models.Model):
    author=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 700)

Class Chapter(models.Model):
    manga = models.ForeignKey(Manga)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    content = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

**Views.py**

```
class MangaAddView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/login'
    model = Manga
    template_name = 'manageManga/manga_add.html'
    form_class = MangaRegistrationForm
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        self.object = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

class ChapterAddView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/login'
    model = Chapter
    template_name = 'manageManga/chapter_add.html'
    form_class = ChapterRegistrationForm
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        manga_id = # forma de obtener el id
        form.instance.manga = Manga.objects.filter(id=manga_id)
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        self.object = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^mangas/add$', views.MangaAddView.as_view(), name = 'manga_add'),
    url(r'^mangas/(?P<manga_id>[0-9]+)/chapter/add$', views.ChapterAddView.as_view(), name = 'chapter_add'),#aqui es por donde quiero pasar la id o pk
]
```

Los formularios no son nada especial, simplemente en ellos omito los campos author del modelo Manga y owner & manga del modelo Chapter.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy sencillo amigo. Para ese punto tienes mas de medio camino recorrido.

Puedes darte cuenta que django cuando ve que hay grupos en las expresiones regulares de las urls, las agrupa en un diccionario que luego le pasa a las vistas, y puedes encontrarlo en `self.kwargs` en cualquier método de la clase que uses, en tu caso sería así:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    manga_id = self.kwargs['manga_id']# forma de obtener el id
    form.instance.manga = Manga.objects.filter(id=manga_id)
    form.instance.owner = self.request.user
    self.object = form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Espero haberte ayudado, cualquier duda comenta

Comment: Gracias, me fue muy útil, por cierto sabes como añadir un error al formulario, por ejemplo que la id no pertenezca a ningún objeto redirigir a otra pagina, o que si el usuario que creo el objeto del cual obtengo la id no sea el mismo que esta creando el objeto actual no dar acceso a esa url?

Comment: **Actualizacion**:Para no dejar entrar si el objeto con esa id no existe modifique el método get añadiendo un get_object_or_404

Comment: **Actualizacion 2** :Para no dejar entrar si el usuario que creo el objeto con esa id y el usuario logeado no coinciden realice un if en el método get que verifica si coinciden, si no coinciden hace un HttpResponse y si coinciden hace un return super(ChapterAddView, self).get(request). Me funciona muy bien, pero si se te ocurre una idea diferente de como hacerlo me gustaría saberla, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si tienes más preguntas, añádelas editando la pregunta inicial, o creando otra pregunta en caso de no ser acerca del problema inicial, recuerda que SO es para preguntas específicas, no para hacer mejoras de código, y si la respuesta te fue de ayuda, no olvides calificarla y marcar la pregunta como resuelta para que futuros usuarios puedan ver.